# A second-order linear differential equation related to an electrical circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

If a circuit is activated by the electromotive force **$E=V_0\sin(nt)$** where $t$ and $V_0$ are constants, then the current **I** at time **t** satisfies the differential equation $$L\frac{d^2I}{dt^2} + R\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{1}{C} I=\frac{dE}{dt}$$ where $C$, $L$ and $R$ are constants and positive.

1) Describe how **I** varies with **t** when $CR^2\gt4L$

2) Show that after some time it settles to a regular oscillation given by $I=a\sin(nt) + b\cos(nt)$, where **a** and **b** are constants, and hence show that this can be written in the form $I=K\sin(nt+\alpha)$, where $K$ and $\alpha$ are constants.

3) Hence ultimately express $K$ in terms of $V_0$, $C,$ $L,$ $R,$ and $n.$

My approach is as follows: $$\frac{dE}{dt}=nV_0\cos(nt)$$ $$L\frac{d^2I}{dt^2} + R\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}I=nV_0\cos(nt)$$ Then I tried to find the complementary function: $$L\lambda^2+R\lambda+\frac{1}{C}=0$$ $$\lambda=-\frac{R\pm\sqrt{(CR^2-4L)\frac{1}{C}}}{2L}$$ Next I tried to find the particular solution by letting **$I=a\sin(nt)+b\cos(nt)$** and substitute into $L\frac{d^2I}{dt^2} + R\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}I=nV_0\cos(nt)$ which ultimately brought me to the result $a=b=\frac{V_0}{2R}$ and this gives $K$ to be $\sqrt{2}\frac{V_0}{2R}$ which is of course wrong.

**K** is supposedly $$\frac{V_0n}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{C}-Ln^2)^2+R^2n^2}}$$

Help would be much appreciated, at the level of an A-level student please.

Comment: Please consider writing a better title to your question

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits. One writes $a\cos t,$ not $a cos t,$ and $A\pm B,$ not $A+/-B.$ When in doubt, google "latex symbols".

Comment: @Harry49 but surely that will be testing if $K sin(nt+\alpha)$ is a solution to the differential equation instead of testing if the differential equation can be expressed in such form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your substitution:
$$
\begin{array}{ccrlcrl}
\frac{1}{C}I&=&\frac{a}{C}&\sin(nt)&+&\frac{b}{C}&\cos(nt) \\
R\frac{dI}{dt}&=&-Rnb&\sin(nt)&+&Rna&\cos(nt) \\
L\frac{d^2I}{dt^2}&=&-Ln^2a&\sin(nt)&+&-Ln^2b&\cos(nt) \\
\hline
nV_0\cos(nt)&=&\left(\left(\frac{1}{C}-Ln^2\right)a-Rnb\right)&\sin(nt)&+&\left(\left(\frac{1}{C}-Ln^2\right)b-Rna\right)&\cos(nt)
\end{array}
$$
Matching the coefficients gives the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rlcrll}
\left(\frac{1}{C}-Ln^2\right)&a&+&-Rn&b&=0 \\
-Rn&a&+&\left(\frac{1}{C}-Ln^2\right)&b&=nV_0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It should be clear from this why your $a$ and $b$ don't work, and this is a linear system (albeit a complicated one) so it shouldn't give you too much difficulty.

Comment: Ah, these are the exact steps I got to, I think I didn't actually factor out the a and b and simply took one away from the other, it was a silly error shouldn't have been made. Thank you for your answer.